# vue-chart.js : Data available as computed properties, but not showing in chart

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

Data is available in computed properties (see screenshot), but won't render out into the PieChart control..

Anyone got any idea why ?

**CODE :**

```
<script>
import { Pie } from 'vue-chartjs'
import * as types from '../store/mutationtypes'
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default Pie.extend({
  mounted () {
    statOrderStatus : this.$store.dispatch('getStatisticsForOrderStatus'),
    this.renderChart({
    labels: this.orderStatusChartKeys,
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Ticketstatus',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: this.orderStatusChartData
        }
      ]
    })

  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["statOrderStatus"]),
    orderStatusChartData () {
      let chartData = []
      this.statOrderStatus.forEach(function(orderStatus) {
          chartData.push(orderStatus.doc_count)
      })      
      return chartData
    },
    orderStatusChartKeys () {
      let chartKeys = []
      this.statOrderStatus.forEach(function(orderStatus) {
          chartKeys.push(orderStatus.key)
      })      
      return chartKeys
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

**VUE info : (Chrome debug)**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try making a computed property to calculate the chart data:

Look at `chart.js` at https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpNBtUKQ67-jSFRHtNe

```
datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Ticketstatus',
          backgroundColor: '#f87979',
          data: this.orderStatusChartData
        }
```

.

```
computed: {
    orderStatusChartData () {
      let chartData = []
      this.statOrderstatus.forEach(function(orderStatus) {
          chartData.push(orderStatus.doc_count)
      })      
      return chartData
    }
```

Comment: thanx @daniel-d :)

I have only one issue here.. I'll update the question :

Comment: Updated the question with lastest code, error message, and a screenshot of  State.. Hope this is helpful for solving :)

Comment: You're trying to set the data of the pie chart to an array of string values.  You need to set it to the array of number values:

    datasets: [
            {
              ...
              data: this.orderStatusChartData
            }.  Basically you just mixed up your `orderStatusChartData` and `orderStatusChartKeys` in your chart code.

Comment: Thanks for the response @daniel-d :) It was unfortunately the same result though.. screenshot (as linked in the question) is exactly like now : Only that red short bar on top, no chart... Any other things you might think could be missing ? PS! I have tried it with the demo-data, and it displayed correctly.. Could it be an issue with datatype ? both should be arrays? I have tried with both []'s and {}'s around with no success on that either...

Comment: I don't know Terje.  The `orderStatusChartData` looks good in the inspector.  It should be working as far as I can see.

Comment: I updated the webpackbin for this question.  Check it out, it might help: https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KpNBtUKQ67-jSFRHtNe

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149756/discussion-between-terje-nygard-and-daniel-d).

Comment: Seems like your way, by passing the data as props is the way to go.. got it figured out now, by doing exactly that.. Thanks Daniel :)

Comment: I have the same problem, and I tried to implement your solution here (created separate computed functions for labels and data and then passed to mounted `this.renderChart` as you did in your webpackbin) but alas it still won't draw anything other than the title on my chart (I am using a bar chart btw). Do you have any other suggestions or tips? This is driving me crazy.